# Socket reusing with boost asio

Tags: sockets, boost, bind, boost-asio, reusability

I try to use a boost asio socket, bound to a local address/port combination. That works great. What doesn't work, is the re-using of the socket once the socket and application has been stopped and restarted.

```
    //
    // open the socket - it would also be opened by the async_connect() 
    // method but we might need an open socket to bind it
    _socket.open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4());

    if ( _bindLocal ) {
        boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address option(true);
        _socket.set_option(option);
        _socket.bind( _localEndpoint );
    }

    // Invoke async. connect. Immediate return, no throw.
    _socket.async_connect(_remoteEndpoint,
        boost::bind(&MyTransceiver::handleConnect, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

What am I missing? Is the ordering of the open(), set_option() and bind() call correct?

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine. Try to use error_code to get the result of your set_option() call.

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
_socket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true), ec);
```

Comment: I have the error code, it's 0. The subsequent call to the async_connect() throws, that the address can't be used twice. Same as if the set_option() woudldn't be there.

Comment: I must say that I'm on windows and the netstat output says "waiting" of the used socket.

Comment: Do you mean time_wait? It is correct state, that is why you need to set reuse_address to ture. Maybe you can try to use winsock API setsockopt() to set the SO_REUSEADDR property to the underlying socket directly.

Comment: Yes, time_wait - I have a different native windows language. That is exactly why I want to set it on the boost socket. As I am using the boost library, I don't want to fiddle with the underlaying socket directly...